# Objective C: Making a json object from dictionary error. Dictionary values can only be strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, dictionary

I need to get a Json of the form

```
{
   "_requestName":"login",
   "_ParamNames":[
      "userId",
      "password"
   ],
   "userId":"GFM",
   "password":"a"
}
```

So I am doing:

```
NSString *username=self.unTextField.text;
NSString *password=self.pwdTextField.text;
NSArray *params=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"userId",@"password", nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"_requestName", @"login",
                   @"_ParamNames", params,
                   @"userId", username,
                   @"password", password,
                   nil];
if (![NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dictionary]) {
    [self.validationTextField setText:@"Cannot make valid JSON"];
}
```

I get an error because I'm trying to store the `NSArray` `params` as a value in `dictionary`. The text field does show "Cannot make valid JSON". How do I fix this? The Json MUST be sent in that same format.

Comment: That's not why you're getting the error -- NSArrays in a JSON structure are fine.  There may be a limitation regarding the leading `_` in key names (check the syntax at json.org), or you may have a non-string for one of your variable "strings".

Comment: His variables look to be taken from textfield's `text` property, which leaves them only as strings or `nil`, the latter of which would crash before the `if` statement.

Comment: Run `dataWithJsonObject` with an `error` parm to get a precise error message.

Comment: @HotLicks how do I run with error param? I put error:error instead of error:nil and it gives error saying error undefined.

Comment: @Kartik_Koro Did you try defining an `error` param?

Comment: And NSLog your objects to see if they look right -- doing that would have identified the bug Alladinian points out.

Comment: (And you should always use the error parm, and log it if the translation fails.  Real men check errors.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you got keys/objects the other way round (first come the objects *then* the keys in the method). A better solution would be to just use some literals. Something like this:

```
NSString *username= @"u";
NSString *password= @"p";

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
    @"_requestName": @"login",
    @"_ParamNames": @[
        @"userId",
        @"password"
    ],
    @"userId": username,
    @"password": password
};

if (![NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dictionary]) {
    NSLog(@"Cannot make valid JSON");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Hooray!");
}
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, I missed that one!  I rarely use the objectsAndKeys form, so it wasn't obvious.

Comment: This answer might be slightly better if you used the same method for creating the dictionary.  It's confusing that you say the keys/values are misordered then show a code snippet with a different order albeit a different method of creating the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks alot! that worked well. I guess it is sort of confusing to enter value:key instead of key:value for that method, key:value is generally standard right? The way you defined the dictionary is alot simpler and easier way to define. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this working fine .. and also get output in JSON String

```
 NSString *username=self.unTextField.text;
NSString *password=self.pwdTextField.text;
NSArray *params=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"userId",@"password", nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"login", @"_requestName",
                          params,@"_ParamNames",
                         username, @"userId",
                          password, @"password",
                          nil];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:nil];
NSString *JSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"printing data %@",JSONString);
```

Comment: OK, I missed that you were creating the array first.